Trying to call sidebar in html using jQuery and it's not working?
I want to set up a template with a navbar, sidebar, etc. that I can call for several different html files. I tried copying and pasting the suggested jQuery code and I can't get it to work. I don't understand what I could be doing wrong. I tried changing the jQuery version to the most recent one. I tried downloading jQuery. I even downloaded it straight into the directory too. I'm using local host and running on Chrome if that makes a difference. The sidebar is from, I think, bootstrap's website.
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#sidebar").load("sidebar.html");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</body>

</html>


sidebar.html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Serif+Text&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sidebar" class="col-2 p-3 text-white bg-dark">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#home" />
          </svg>
          AC
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#speedometer2" />
          </svg>
          Acura
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#table" />
          </svg>
          Alfa Romeo
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#grid" />
          </svg>
          Alpine
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#people-circle" />
          </svg>
          Aston Martin
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
</body>

</html>


You are using the slim version of jQuery. This version doesn't include AJAX functionalities like load(). You should use the full version of jQuery.
It's best practice to ensure that your jQuery code runs after the DOM has finished loading. You can achieve this by wrapping your code inside $(document).ready().


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>
         // Ensure jQuery code runs after DOM has loaded
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sidebar").load("sidebar.html");
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</body>

</html>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Serif+Text&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sidebar" class="col-2 p-3 text-white bg-dark">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#home" />
          </svg>
          AC
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#speedometer2" />
          </svg>
          Acura
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#table" />
          </svg>
          Alfa Romeo
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#grid" />
          </svg>
          Alpine
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16">
            <use xlink:href="#people-circle" />
          </svg>
          Aston Martin
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



